# Why do the password labels not indicate that a password is required?

Tags: profile, joomla, forms, user-account

A minor issue perhaps because for most it is self-evident that an account needs a password, still: all fields that are required get a coloured asterix after the label, but not the two password fields.
Why is that?
How can I add these asterixs?

[image: no asterix]

Comment: This is a Joomla question, not a CiviCRM question as far as I can see?

Comment: Well, no. Perhaps an in-between question. The css and the label text and the descriptive text are all civicrm code. Probably it is in the part that syncs the Joomla-part with the CiviCRM core. (With Joomla this is coded in the users component part, in overridable text files and the template css. And there asterixes are available.)